# Apply bootstrap class to all child anchors in angular component

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My googling has failed me...

My angular component contains a boolean variable, `isAuthenticated` that is changed to true/false depending on login status (in typescript file).

```html
<div id="sidebar-container" class="sidebar-expanded col-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light" >
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/" [ngClass]="isAuthenticated ? '' : 'disabled'">Overview</a>
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="settings" [ngClass]="isAuthenticated ? '' : 'disabled'">Settings</a>
</div>
```

The `[ngClass]="isAuthenticated ? '' : 'disabled'` is repeated for each anchor tag.

What can I do to only write the if-statement once??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to apply DRY coding principles to your menu items. In model:

```
public get menuItems() {
  return [
    { path: '/', title: 'Overview' },
    { path: 'settings', title: 'Settings' }
  ];
}
```

In template:

```
<div id="sidebar-container">
  <a *ngFor="let item of menuItems"
     [routerLink]="[item.path]" 
     [ngClass]="['nav-link', { disabled: !isAuthenticated }]">
    {{item.title}}
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Or... `class="nav-link" [class.disabled]="!isAuthenticated"`

Comment: @developer033, indeed, you can pass classes to an element using `class`, `[class]` and `[ngClass]`. In general I tend to use the latter as I can combine both array (for non-conditional) with object notations (for conditional). But the question was actually how to write it DRY (not repeat for each item), and it looks like I'm the only one who properly answered the question.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't mean to diminish your answer at all, instead I wanted to offer another syntax to complement your answer. It's more a personal preference, but I don't see any value in putting a static value as `nav-link` into the binding `ngClass`. Also, one thing I noticed looking at a second time now is that you suggested putting the items in a `getter`. Please, don't! Assign them to a variable. And yes, your answer is the only one that makes sense for what the OP needs :)

Comment: @developer033, grouping them under one attribute is a personal preference but, overall, I'd say it's a good practice. In time I have tried to develop ways to gain as much control as possible over code with minimal focus effort. I've learned that having, on the same element, `class` and `:class`(in Vue) or `class` and `[ngClass]` or `[class]` in angular, or `class` and `className` in React is prone to losing more time in order to fix things, especially when the two attributes become separated by a few other attributes. That's the main reason behind trying to group them under only one attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by doing some css hack.

just set a conditional unique css class in the parent div.

```
<div id="sidebar-container"  class="sidebar-expanded col-2 d-none  .  
 d-md-block bg-light" [ngClass]="!isAuthenticated ? '' : 'disabled'" >
```

add below css in the `.css` file :

```
.disabled a{
  pointer-events: none;
  color : grey;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

As you can see the css will apply on all the child anchors of `disabled class`.

[**Working example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1zszq)

Comment: This would be the correct way to go, if Bootstrap didn't already come with predefined styles for anchors having the class `disabled` (and it looks like OP is trying to make use of those, rather than writing their own custom CSS). Not that I consider writing your own CSS wrong.

Comment: @andrei see the question that has been asked first. He didn't want disabled condition in every `a` . That's why I proposed this solution

Comment: You're applying `disabled` class on the parent. OP wants to apply it on each of the children, because Bootstrap already contains styling for `a.disabled`. OP doesn't want to mess around with text, border and background colors of hover, active, focus and active hover states. They want the default styling of `a.disabled` aplied, without knowing what it consists of, and without having to write the ternary for each item in the menu. To put it in perspective: your solution only works when you already know the bootstrap theme applied. And breaks when you change the theme.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu its not about `disabled` class. The name of the class can be anything. And your statement is wrong because the style gets applied on `a` not on the parent. It's just that the `conditional class` that gets added  into parent and its children gets disabled after it , which is what OP wanted .

Comment: We're clearly reading the question differently. You might be right and I might be wrong. Enjoy your evening!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu see this . :  `The [ngClass]="isAuthenticated ? '' : 'disabled' is repeated for each anchor tag.` and he wanted to eliminate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201171/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-programoholic).

Comment: I chose @AndreiGheorghiu:s answer as the correct one since I want to spend as little time as possible in the css:files (personal preference). However your answer is a nice complement for those who might not be able to solve it only using pre-made classes.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your code like this -

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/" [ngClass]="{'disabled': !isAuthenticated}">Overview</a>
```